# Get several JSON object printed to the page

Tags: javascript, json

**I'm making a site where** the user will be able to search for a country and the city or cities in that country will show on the page. I'm able to show one city now for each country but if the country have two or more cities only one of the cities shows. I tried the "+=" to create several cards that will show on the page. That created some issues for me. I'm thinking that I have to use the "appendChild()" function to append each city card to a new div in the DOM. But i'm not 100% sure how to do that, with this code.

If I type in "USA" in the searchfield and USA both have LA and NY as cities. The first one shows now, but I want both to show. I've tried using document.createElement('cityCard') and append cityCard to the container where the cards show. But I did not get it to work as I wanted, I might have done some syntax mistake.

Is this the rigth mindset for this task? Or is it a better way?

*Don't mind the CSS, its not done.*

**Link to a fiddle where all the code is.**

https://jsfiddle.net/uzfb852g/12/

added the code under aswell(its the same as in the fiddle)

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Martel:400,700,900" 
rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>FINN DITT FERIESTED!</h1>
<form id="inputForm">
    <input type="text" id="sokFelt">
    <button id="btn">Search</button>
    <button id="allBtn">Alle steder</button>
</form>
<div id="break"></div>
<div id="searchWord"></div>
<div id="cardContainer">
    <div id="cityCards">
        <h2 id="country"></h2>
        <h4 id="city"></h4>
        <img id="cityImg">
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btnTwo"></button>

<script src="content.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
body{
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

h1{
text-align: center;
margin: 25px;
color: tomato;
font-family: 'Martel', serif;
text-shadow: 1px 2px #333;
font-weight: 900;
}

#inputForm{
text-align: center;
margin: 25px;
}

#break{
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
height: 1px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #333;
}

#btn{
padding: 5px 15px;
}

#sokFelt{
padding: 5px 15px;
}

#searchWord{
font-size: 24px;
margin: 40px;
color: #333;
font-weight: bold;
}

#cardContainer{
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

#cityCards{
padding: 12px 22px;
background-color: aqua;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 20%;
height: 250px;
}

#cityImg{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}

#allBtn{
padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

**JS CODE:**

```
var form = document.getElementById('inputForm');
var input = form.querySelector('input');
var country = document.getElementById("country");
var city = document.getElementById("city");
var cityImg = document.getElementById("cityImg");
var searchWord = document.getElementById("searchWord");

/*IMAGES*/

var place = [
{land: 'Norge', by: 'Oslo', img: 'img/Oslo.jpg'},
{land: 'USA', by: 'Los Angeles', img: "img/LA.jpg"},
{land: 'USA', by: 'New York', img: "img/NewYork.jpg"},
{land: 'Tyskland', by: 'Berlin', img: 'img/berlin.jpg'},
{land: 'Frankrike', by: 'Paris', img:'img/berlin.jpg'}
];

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
    for(var i = 0; i < place.length; i += 1){
        if(input.value === place[i].land) {
            searchWord.innerHTML = input.value;
            document.createElement('cityCards');
            country.innerHTML = place[i].land;
            city.innerHTML = place[i].by;
            cityImg.src = place[i].img;
        } 
    }
 });


document.getElementById("btnTwo").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.createElement("")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see the problem:

```
 country.innerHTML += place[i].land;
 city.innerHTML += place[i].by;
```

`citycards` is not an HTML element

You must use an array with div´s `(array[i]=document.createElement('div'))`

Then create images with `img[i] = document.createElement('img')`
Set the `img.src`, and append this with `appendChild` to cardcontainer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `createElement` and `appendChild` would be the right way to go, but you could also use a [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) tag instead.

Then you could just fill the template with the filtered information and import the template to the DOM.

Here is an example on how this could look like. You may want to take a look at the [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) function `filter`, `map` and `forEach`.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('inputForm');
var input = form.querySelector('input');
var searchWord = document.getElementById("searchWord");
var template = document.querySelector('#cardContainer');
var getAllBtn = document.getElementById('allBtn');
var place=[{land:"Norge",by:"Oslo",img:"http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/destination/article137625.ece/ALTERNATES/w460/oslocityhall.jpg"},{land:"USA",by:"Los Angeles",img:"http://www.zocalopublicsquare.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/DistantLASkylineBIG-levinson.jpg"},{land:"USA",by:"New York",img:"https://www.city-journal.org/sites/cj/files/New-York.jpg"},{land:"Tyskland",by:"Berlin",img:"http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/Destinations/Europe/Germany/Berlin/Berlin%20cathedral-xlarge.jpg"}];

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

getAllBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // clear your container div to empty all previous added elements.
  searchWord.innerHTML = "";
  // filter your place data on the land property of each item.
  place.filter( item => item.land === input.value )
  // set the img src attr and text content for the elements in the template.
    .map( item => {
    template.content.getElementById("country").textContent = item.land;
    template.content.getElementById("city").textContent = item.by;
    template.content.getElementById("cityImg").src = item.img;
    return document.importNode(template.content, true);
  })
  // append them to your container element.
    .forEach( item => {
    searchWord.appendChild(item)
  })
});
```

```css
body{margin:auto;width:100%;height:100%}h1{text-align:center;margin:25px;color:tomato;font-family:'Martel',serif;text-shadow:1px 2px #333;font-weight:900}#inputForm{text-align:center;margin:25px}#break{width:80%;margin:auto;height:1px;text-align:center;background-color:#333}#btn{padding:5px 15px}#sokFelt{padding:5px 15px}#searchWord{font-size:24px;margin:40px;color:#333;font-weight:700}#cardContainer{width:100%;margin:auto;display:flex;flex-direction:column;flex-wrap:wrap}#cityCards{padding:12px 22px;background-color:aqua;border-radius:5px;width:20%;height:250px}#cityImg{width:100%;height:200px}#allBtn{padding:5px 15px}
```

```html
<h1>VACATION</h1>
<form id="inputForm">
    <input type="text" id="sokFelt">
    <button id="btn">Search</button>
    <button id="allBtn">All places</button>
</form>
<div id="break"></div>
<div id="searchWord"></div>
<template id="cardContainer">
    <div id="cityCards">
        <h2 id="country"></h2>
        <h4 id="city"></h4>
        <img id="cityImg">
    </div>
</template>
```